# Rotating a UIImageView in iOS

Tags: xcode, rotation, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I'm relatively new to iOS programming, and want my first project to include a gauge with rotating needle. So here's what I did...

- Created a new single view based project.
- Dragged a UIImageView onto the centre of the Interface Builder and added my image of a gauge needle.
- Created and IBOutlet for my image into the header file called imgNeedle
- Created the following method in the implementation file and run it on an NSTimer:

> ```
> -(void) rotateNeedle {
>     degrees++;         
>     radians = degrees / 57.2958;
>
>     [self.imgNeedle setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians)];
> }
> ```

The needle does actually rotate, but it's not around a static point. It's a little difficult to explain but it seems that the image is anchored at the top left corner? It might be worth knocking together a quick project if I haven't explained the problem very well! :)

However, if I create the UIImageView at runtime, by placing the following code before the NSTimer in the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIImageView *Needle = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 100, 10)];

self.imgNeedle = Needle;

self.imgNeedle.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"needle.jpg"];
[self.view addSubview:self.imgNeedle];
```

Then it behaves how I'd like it to, rotating around a central fixed point.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed, thank you!